# Why doesn't Ollivander work with the Elder wood?

Tags: harry-potter, wandlore, deathly-hallows

Since Elder  is the name of a wand wood, why don't we see more Elder wands. I only remember the famous  **Elder wand created by death**.

P.S. **I am asking only about Ollivander since he doesn't believe in "wand of elder, never prosper"**.

Comment: Given that my answer specifically addresses why ***Ollivander*** won't work with Elder, I'm struggling to understand why you've accepted the other answer which only speaks to wandmakers in general...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Wands of elder never prosper* comes from *Tales of Beedle the Bard*, not from Mr. Ollivander himself (I'm noting this purely for the sake of clarity. I realize you already know this, but some readers might not :) ). Here is the reason wandmakers, of which Ollivander is one, don't like to use elder wood for wands:

> Whether because of the fact that Death makes the fictional wand out of elder in Beedle’s story, or because power-hungry or violent wizards have persistently claimed that their own wands are made of elder, it is not a wood that is much favoured among wandmakers.
>   <sub>*Tales of Beedle the Bard* - Bloomsbury - *The Tale of the Three Brothers*</sub>

Answer (score 34):

[Pottermore](http://pottermore.wikia.com/wiki/Wand_Woods) has a bit more information about wandlore specifically relating to the creation of wands in elder wood.

According to Ollivander himself, wandmakers tend to avoid it because;

- It's difficult to work with.
- It's perceived to be unlucky (**which means they're difficult to sell**).
- The wands are notoriously disloyal.
- Only the most exceptional wizards will be able to master the wand.

> **ELDER :**
>   The rarest wand wood of all, and reputed to be deeply unlucky, the elder wand is trickier to master than any other. It
>   contains powerful magic, but scorns to remain with any owner who is
>   not the superior of his or her company; it takes a remarkable wizard
>   to keep the elder wand for any length of time. The old superstition,
>   ‘wand of elder, never prosper,’ has its basis in this fear of the
>   wand, but in fact, the superstition is baseless, and those **foolish
>   wandmakers who refuse to work with elder do so more because they doubt
>   they will be able to sell their products than from fear of working
>   with this wood. The truth is that only a highly unusual person will
>   find their perfect match in elder, and on the rare occasion when such
>   a pairing occurs, I take it as certain that the witch or wizard in
>   question is marked out for a special destiny.** An additional fact that
>   I have unearthed during my long years of study is that the owners of
>   elder wands almost always feel a powerful affinity with those chosen
>   by rowan.

from *Pottermore*

and

> *Whether because of the fact that Death makes the fictional wand out of elder in Beedle’s story, or **because power-hungry or violent wizards
>   have persistently claimed that their own wands are made of elder, it
>   is not a wood that is much favoured among wandmakers**.*

From "*The Tales of Beedle the Bard*".

Comment: I have already read it but Its irrelevant here

Comment: @TomLynd - Why is Richard's answer irrelevant? It's a canon answer ... ?

Comment: Why doesn't **Ollivander** work with the Elder wood.?

Comment: @TomLynd - Because he can't sell them. Point 2 on my list.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: @human - I know, right?